# Error code #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I got an error on the output window. I got serval layers, the first layer on frame 2 there is this function wich goes to frame 3 and stops(Located below). But the frame 3 is located on a diffrent layer. The frame 3 dosent has any codes of the frame 2, its simply a empty layer with some graphics. I think it is trying to run the code from frame 2, but it dosen't finds it. I dont know how to solve this problem, but it slows down the application, because the error is looping.

**When it goes to a different frame i get the error**

(Cannot acces a property of null)

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, SquareCircleHit);
function SquareCircleHit(event:Event):void{
    if (square.hitTestObject(circle)) {
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error#1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875701/error1009-cannot-access-a-property-or-method-of-a-null-object-reference)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.  Edit your original question if there are changes or to be clearer.